# Winforms control to display a scrollable list

Tags: winforms, user-controls

I'm writing a wi-fi net detector and I would like to list the results in a list similar to the one Windows uses for displaying networks. What control should I use?

And by the way, is there a winforms equivalent of [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ui/features/components.html)? I've also seen similar diagrams for GTK and Cocoa. That would be helpful for Winforms.

Comment: Not a real answer but rather a suggestion: Winforms controls provided by the .NET framework are quite limited when it comes to fancy displays, is WPF an option for you?

Comment: It is, but I have no experience with it. But feel free to suggest an answer, I might go with it.

Comment: From this perspective the main advantage of WPF would be that it permits creatively compositing the UI elements used to display a list item (while retaining the list functionality), allowing pretty much anything from simple simple stuff like this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx to extreme cases like this one: http://richapps.wordpress.com/2009/02/12/advanced-styling-wpf/#.

Comment: Sorry for giving you only teasing links instead of a full answer, I'm just not sure what a good answer would be in this context...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say your best best would be a ListBox control.  It will allow you to scroll, you can permit single select or multi-select, and a number of other things.

As for a visual guide to all of the Winform controls, I don't know of any site that does that directly.  The closest thing that I know of is a list of all of the controls that has a picture of each when you click on it (as well as how to work with it).  Here is the link:

[http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0460_*GUI-Windows-Forms/Catalog0460*_GUI-Windows-Forms.htm](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0460__GUI-Windows-Forms/Catalog0460__GUI-Windows-Forms.htm)